# Using MongoClient How to check connection details is valid or not with Mongo .Net driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB / .Net world. Using MongoDB .Not Driver 2.4.3, Trying to connect Mongo DB using MongoClient and check if DB exists or not then do some operations with DB.

```
 try
 {
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017");

    bool isDatabaseExist = false;

    IAsyncCursor<BsonDocument> cursor = client.ListDatabases();
    cursor.ForEachAsync(d => isDatabaseExist = (d["name"] == "test_db"));
   // If exist ....
   ...
   // Else
   ...
}
catch (MongoException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message );
}
```

In this above code sample If I pass invalid credential then it's popping up exception **"A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector..."** again and again.

Why it's showing timeout error again and again instead of giving some relavant error?

How to know that it's not valid connection details?

Comment: where is your mongodb hosted?

Comment: Alex, It's hosted on Windows 7 machine in the same domain for which I am not exposing IP.